# Ionic on ios emulator - loaded website cannot be scrolled

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I am loading website in my application index.html by:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.location.replace('http://website.com');
}
```

The page is loaded normally but I cannot scroll it.
I have tried iphone `5`, `5s`, `6` emulator and it's not working but on android is working normally.

When I open safari on iphone emulator and go to the website it can be scrolled normally. I have tried all combinations of DisallowOverscroll and UIWebViewBounce Preferencesin `config.xml`.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and Ionic.

Is anyone has the same problem?

Comment: use `ion-scroll` in ion-content of the page..http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I bought an Iphone 5 and tested the application on it and scrolling works normally. It looks like there was some problem with emulator.